# How to select only one result per condition met inside an individual table (no joins)?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing all the trips taken by different cars. I've filtered down this table to trips that had multiple stops specifically. Now all i want to do is get the first stop that each car had.

What i've got is:

```
Car ID
Date_depart
Date_arrive
Count (from a previous table creation)
```

I've filtered this table by using Car ID + Date Depart and making a count where there are multiple date_arrives for a single date_depart. Now i'm trying to figure out how to only get back the first stop but am completely stuck. Outside of doing the lateral join X, order by Z limit 1 etc method; i have no idea how to get back only the first result in this table.

Here's some sample data:

```
Car ID     Date_depart     Date_arrive    Count
949        2017-01-01      2017-01-05     2
949        2017-01-01      2017-01-09     2
1940       2017-01-09      2017-01-11     3
1940       2017-01-09      2017-01-14     3
1940       2017-01-09      2017-01-28     3
949        2018-04-19      2018-04-23     2
949        2018-04-19      2018-04-26     2
```

and the expected result would be:

```
Car ID     Date_depart     Date_arrive    Count
949        2017-01-01      2017-01-05     2
1940       2017-01-09      2017-01-11     3
949        2018-04-19      2018-04-23     2
```

Any help?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need the `min` aggregate function to get the earliest `date_arrive` from your current sample data. If you provide the actual query I should be able to help with a proper answer and an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need `DISTINCT ON`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_depart, car_id)
    *
FROM 
    trips
ORDER BY date_depart, car_id, date_arrive
```

This gives you the first (ordered) row of each group `(date_depart, car_id)`

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=60bf6b1ec7f6748f30e249cb94899565)

Comment: @EdwardGorelik Did this help? If not, how can I help you? If so, please don't forget to upvote (to honor the replier) and accept (to show others that your problem has been solved)